# Image in span tag into an img tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I try to display an image with `<img src="" alt="music cover">` using `<span></span>` to display the music covers of my web radio.

The link is dynamic, it's why I want to use the span tag for getting the url link of the image's shown during music playback.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<center>
  <p class="current-playlist">
    <span></span>
  </p>
</center>
```

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<center><p class="current-playlist"><img src="<span></span"></p></center>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <script>
         var nowPlayingTimeout;
var nowPlaying;

function loadNowPlaying() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'https://my_radio_website.com/api/nowplaying_static/radio.json',
        success: function(np) {
            // Do something with the Now Playing data.
            nowPlaying = np;
              $('.current-playlist span').text(np.now_playing.song.art);

            nowPlayingTimeout = setTimeout(loadNowPlaying, 15000);
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        nowPlayingTimeout = setTimeout(loadNowPlaying, 30000);
    });
}

$(function() {
    loadNowPlaying();
});
</script>
</html>
```

Without the img tag, only the image link is shown, how could I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<img src="<span></span">` is not a valid HTML, you can not put another element into `src` tag, you should only set image link to `src` instead.

To do that, you can crate an `<img src="">` element with an empty `src` attribute.

Then, when you need to load the image you can put the image link into `src` attribute.

Example:

```js
const imageLink = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";

// setTimout to simulate ajax request
setTimeout(() => {
  $(".current-playlist img").attr("src", imageLink);
  // OR document.querySelector('.current-playlist img').src = imageLink;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="current-playlist">
  <img src="">
</p>
```